# Natural Language/Text Mining and Reddit/social news site

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval, text-mining

I think there is a wealth of natural language data associated with sites like reddit or digg or news.google.com.

I have done a little bit of research with text mining, but can't find how I could use those tools to parse something like reddit.

What kind of applications can you come up with?

Comment: Double check tag spelling, also note the syntax is dash for multi-word tags, ie 'natural-language'

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'to parse' Reddit or Google Mail? If you just want to scrape them for links, this question is not nlp-related. If you want to parse the content (like 'OMFG Nekkid kittenz' in the case of Reddit), please refine your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found in the past that the best way to mine data on sites like Reddit or Digg is to first use the developer API that they provide. Typically you have a focused interest in either a topic or trend, and the only way to get that data is through an established public interface. You can also parse feeds, and combine them both to uncover 90% of what you would want to know. If you want to do deep research on data not available through an API, then you should be prepared to spend a significant amount of time writing custom wrappers around a tool like cURL. If you have the budget you can also call them and ask if they offer paid research data on users.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start on the [RSS](http://www.reddit.com/.rss), and after that I might use [Nutch](http://lucene.apache.org/nutch/); what to actually do with the data is more your call.

Answer (score 0):

These are good ideas.  I can get the data, but what applications can be built around it?